# C++ unordered_map<T, int> how to distinguish null cell from 0

Tags: c++, unordered-map

Suppose I have an `unordered_map<string, int> H`.

Let's say there is no element "house" in H, so `cout<<H["house"];` would print 0.

But suppose I need to assign `H["house"] = 0`.

How would I distinguish an element that doesn't exist from one that is 0?

```
//example of what I want:

if(!H["house"]){
    cout<<"DOES NOT EXIST YET\n";
    H["house"] = 0;
}

if(H["house"]){
    cout<<"IT EXISTS NOW\n";
}
```

Comment: Using `.find` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shortest test:

```
if (H.count("house")) {
    // "house" exists
} else {
    // "house" does not exist in H
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In an `std::unordered_map`, `operator[]` modifies the map if the element does not exist.  This is to allow simple assignment statements like `H["house"] = 0` to work.  When doing look up, you really don't want this.

Instead, you should either use `H.find`, or use `H.at`.  `find` returns an iterator, which will compare equal to `H.end()` if the element cannot be found, and can be dereferenced for the value otherwise.  `at` throws an error if the element is not found.

Comment: what would happen with H["house"] if I place it inside an `if(H["house"])` ?

Comment: It would add the `"house" -> 0` mapping to the map and return `0`, causing the `if` to behave as if the expression was false.  I do not recommend this.

Answer (score 1):

```
auto itr = H.find("house");
if (itr == H.end())
{
    // "house" does not exist in H
}
else
{
    // "house" exists
    // itr->second = the same as H["house"]
}
```

Comment: Since C++17 maybe better: `if (auto it = H.find("house"); it != H.end()) house_exists(*it); else build_house();`

Comment: @Deduplicator Yes, that's correct, but it's worth noting that (*it) in your example is a std::pair<>, not the key or the value.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to `boost`, then a little function to return an optional reference to the mapped type could be useful. If you have a recent c++ implementation, you could use `std::optional`.

```
template<class K, class V, class H, class E, class A, class Lookup>
auto 
maybe_at(std::unordered_map<K,V,H,E,A> const& m, Lookup&& key)
-> boost::optional<V const&>
{
    boost::optional<V const&> result;
    auto i = m.find(key);
    if (i != m.end())
        result = i->second;
    return result;
}
```

example of use:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<class K, class V, class H, class E, class A, class Lookup>
auto 
maybe_at(std::unordered_map<K,V,H,E,A> const& m, Lookup&& key)
-> boost::optional<V const&>
{
    boost::optional<V const&> result;
    auto i = m.find(key);
    if (i != m.end())
        result = i->second;
    return result;
}

void emit(boost::optional<const int&> oi)
{
    if (oi)
    {
        std::cout << *oi << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "{null}" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> m;

    m["house"] = 0;

    emit(maybe_at(m, "house"));
    emit(maybe_at(m, "donkey"));
}
```